# Which wireless keyboards and mice are compatible?

Tags: wireless, keyboard, mouse

Could I know, what wireless keyboard and mouse work fine with ubuntu for a desktop.
Last time I installed it on my desktop, my mouse just got froze!! Then i stopped using it.

I really wanna use ubuntu, and i'm planning to buy this wireless devices. Any help in finding the working wireless keyboard and mouse combo, would be appreciated.

Also I heard most of the Logitech devices freeze on ubuntu!!

Comment: I find the prevalence of answers below that comment on Microsoft branded gear ironic, when thinking about devices that are more likely to work with Linux. Also, despite [roadmr](http://askubuntu.com/users/30589)'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79273/#144257) stating that Logitech mice don't freeze on Ubuntu, while I haven't used this combination, I have read a fair few problems with Logitech keyboard/mice on Linux (Not to say this isn't due to lack of knowledge on manual configuration that needs to be done, or something).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a MS Natural Ergonomic Wireless KB & Mouse.

The mouse works but the keyboard drops connection every half hour. This can be resolved by pressing the connect button so it's a trade-off between that inconvenience and the fact that I find this the most comfortable keyboard I've used (an old wrist injury makes typing on a standard keyboard a bit uncomfortable at times).

(Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: p.s. Sorry that's the '7000' model

Comment: I recommend that you edit your post to include the model number. (I would do so, but I'm not sure if it's for the keyboard, mouse, or both.)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 6000 v3.0 and the Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 v2.0. These work flawlessly with Ubuntu, I would give them a very high recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Logitech mice do NOT freeze on Ubuntu. I have a M310 optical cordless mouse and it's worked flawlessly since day one (it's about 18 months old).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Microsoft Wireless (Keyboard 800+ Mouse 1000). Although I am able to use the basic functions for which they are meant but media keys do not work at all, except the mute button. So, atleast **do not** go for this combination...